# cant see delete/edit buttons in agent list view for campaign, in list view

Tags: permissions, profile, campaign, page-layout

**Problem Description**: for a user with an agent profile, the agent cant see the standard edit/delete buttons in the list view for campaign.
Moreover, the agent, has the profile permissions to read,delete and edit the campaign object, and in his corresponding layout, he has these standard buttons. No global sharing rules.
**my question:** is there another way/reason for not being able to see these buttons in the list view for the campaign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from documentation- [Defining Campaign Access](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_campaign_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_campaign_implementation_guide/campaign_preparation_access.htm):

> Before setting up campaign management, you need to determine who
>   should have access to campaigns. By default, all users have read
>   access to campaigns, while only users with the **Marketing User** checkbox
>   selected on their user record can create, edit, or delete campaigns.

Comment: So just to clarify, as an agent, im creating my own campaign,  and I have the right permissions to edit and delete my campaign, I still cant see the buttons.

Comment: Ok, you are totally right, I was not aware of it. Thank you so much for helping me out